# Multiples queries (N+1) using Eager Loading - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to load all the contacts with the conversation, and it's working unless I try to access the conversation attributes.

```
$contatos = Contato::whereBelongsTo($conta)->with('Conversa')->get();

foreach ($contatos as $contato) {
    $saida_contato = new \stdClass();
    $saida_contato->nome_contato = $contato->nome;
    $saida_contato->id = $contato->id;
    $saida_contato->numero_contato = $contato->id_contato;
    $saida_contato->conta_id = $contato->conta_id;
```

The code above executes two queries:
[image: result of contacts]

When I try to access the attributes of "conversa", it executes 90 queries.

```
 $saida_contato->conversa_aberta = $contato->conversa->first()->id;
```

[image]

I can access the value that I want using:
`contato->conversa[0]->aberta`, but when I do it, it generates a lot of queries.

[image: data]

Why is it executing the query for each contact if I have eager-loaded it before?

Comment: What's your method in `Contato` to define the relationship with `Conversa` ?

Comment: public function Conversa()
    {
        return  $this->hasOne(Conversa::class);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had in my Contato Model:

```
 public function getconversaAttribute()
{

    return $this->conversa()->get();

}
```

so instead of getting the collection when using `$contato->conversa` , i was implicitly calling the method above causing to execute queries.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `first()` from `$contato->conversa->first()->id`

Since you're using a `hasOne` relationship; `$contato->conversa` will returns a `Model` and not a `Collection`.

That's the tricky part. If you're using `first()` on a model, it will be the equivalent of doing `Conversa::first()` and will return the first model of your database through a new query.

Comment: $contato->conversa is an array and when i use $contato->conversa[0]->id,it will execute all the queries too.

Comment: @saidmrn Then you have something else going one somewhere else. I can't think of any case where Laravel would return an array for a relationship. The only thing I can think of is that you're using `hasMany` and not `hasOne` and your array is in fact a Collection. Also, try with Laravel convention by naming your function in `camelCase` (`conversa` no `Conversa`)  and so your eagerloading call.

Comment: Hello,using camelCase returns the same.102 queries, 91 of which are duplicated.
strangest thing is,if i use dd($contato) it returns : https://pastebin.com/AVg4HpbA
that includes all the data i want

Comment: i found the problem but can't understand why
i had the function   public function getconversaAttribute()
    {

        return $this->conversa()->get();

    }
inside my Contato Model,removing it solved the problem. Still executing 5 queries when accessing the value using  $contato->conversa->id

Comment: Ineed adding `getconversaAttribute` will conflict with your relationship. Executing 5 queries may be normal depending on what are there purpose. Eager loading doesn't make one query to get everything you need. It just do the quer**ies** you need to fulfill the requirements.

Comment: Yes,instead of getting 90 queries i'm getting 5 which is expected. Thanks for your help!